# Find Taylor polynomial of an integral function

Tags: calculus, integration

I ran into this problem and I'm absolutely clueless. The problem is:

> Let $f$ be: $$f(x)=\int_0^{\ln(1+2x)} \frac{e^t}{1+t^2}\;dt$$ Find the Taylor polynomial of order $1$ around $x=0$.

The only idea I've had is that you could write $f(x)= F(ln(1+2x))-F(0)$, and then I could use that $f'(x)=F'(ln(1+2x))-F'(0)$, but whenever I try that I always just get $0$.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: You're using $f$ for two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacLaurin expansion is the following
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+O(x^2)$$
If we have
$$f(x)=\int_0^{\ln(1+2x)} \frac{e^t}{1+t^2}\;dt$$
then $f(0)=0$, and by [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{\log (2 x+1)}}{\log ^2(2 x+1)+1}\cdot \frac{2}{2 x+1}=\frac{2 }{\log ^2(2 x+1)+1}$$
and $f'(0)=2$.

Thus expansion is $f(x) = 2x +O(x^2)$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function of x that's defined as the integral from a contant to x, then the derivative of that function is just the integrand evaluated at x.

So if you can do a substitution inside of the integral so that one boundary value is a constant and the other one is just x, you can easily find the nth derivative of your function f

Answer (score 0):

The taylor polynomial formula (around $x=0$) is:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
if we only want the first order polynomial, then we will have the first two terms $x^0,x^1$ and the rest of the terms are neglected and will form our error. This gives:
$$f(x)\approx\frac{f(0)}{0!}x^0+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x=f(0)+f'(0)x\tag{1}$$
now we need to work out these values (the first is given by showing the integrand tends to 1 for $t\to0)$:
$$f(0)=\int_0^{\ln(1)}\frac{e^t}{1+t^2}dt=0$$
$$f'(x)=\frac d{dx}\left[\ln(1+2x)\right]\frac{e^{\ln(1+2x)}}{1+\ln^2(1+2x)}=\frac{2(1+2x)}{(1+2x)(1+\ln^2(1+2x))}=\frac{2}{1+\ln^2(1+2x)}$$
$$\therefore f'(0)=\frac{2}{1+\ln^2(1)}=2$$
and so putting these values into our first equation we get:
$$f(x)\approx 2x$$